# Dapper sql query inner join on List<string>

Tags: c#, dapper

I am trying to run following query but getting an error.

```
conn.Query("select d.ID, d.CategoryID from Document d inner join @Cases c on d.CaseID = c.ID", new { Cases = new List<string> { "000-6575-101", "5902-205" }});
```

When I run the command I receive `Incorrect syntax near ','.`

My question is, is it even possible to do something like what I am doing?

Comment: After a INNER JOIN you need to have a table name. You have a parameter that should represent a list of values. Said that you can't use a parameter to define a table. What is the table that you want to join with Document?

Comment: @Steve " you can't use a parameter to define a table" - well, you can... "table valued parameters", etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dapper support an `in` syntax for this scenario:

```
var ids = new List<string> { "000-6575-101", "5902-205" };
conn.Query("select d.ID, d.CategoryID from Document d where d.CaseID in @ids", new { ids});
```

This is one of the few cases where dapper will actually change your query to do what you want (while remaining fully parameterized, etc).

It also supports (optionally, see `SqlMapper.Settings`):

- parameter padding to reduce query-plan cache saturation
- use of `string_split` on SQL 2016 for integer types (`List<int>` etc)

Comment: What if there are lot's of **ids**? Let's say 200, will that cause an issue?

Comment: it translates to following query, **N'select d.ID, d.CategoryID from Document d where d.CaseID in (@Cases1,@Cases2)',N'@Cases1 nvarchar(4000),@Cases2 nvarchar(4000)',@Cases1=N'000-6575-101',@Cases2=N'5902-205'.** Is parameter **ntext**?

Comment: @Mayank if you prefer to use a TVP, dapper is OK with that too, via `DataTable` (I'm not a huge fan of `DataTable`, but `SqlClient` supports it). The `in` seems to work OK in this scenario, from my experience; the parameter padding helps avoid problems from having 201, 201, 203 etc parameters (by ... padding). If you want control over ansi/unicode: dapper's `DbString` achieves that

Comment: @Mayank I also have on my "todo" list to look at implementing TVP via `IDataReader`, specifically for .net core (which doesn't have `DataTable`).

Comment: Just tried it with list > 500 elements, works fine. Not sure if it's practical with that many elements. Is there a better way to do it for large set?

Comment: @Mayank as I say : TVP via DataTable is an option. And in SQL server 2016, string_split is an option. Dapper doesn't automate the latter for strings, due to the fun of quoting etc, but if you know your data has no quotes, it would be easy to do manually. Weve found that the best results are obtained by using string_split to populate a table variable, then "join" or "in" via the table variable. Don't "join" or "in" to string_split itself.

Comment: We use user-defined-functions...dbo.udf_ConvertIntListToTable(), dbo.udf_ConvertStringListToTable() (plenty of examples on the web)...it looks like x.Col IN (select val from dbo.convertStringListToTable(@s)).  On one hand this is kind of old school.  But the performance is good, and we have integration tests that pipe in tens of thousands of entries and it still runs fine.  When we threw our hands up and said, 'hey, it works, it will be replaced directly by string_split someday...let's just use it' everything became better.

Comment: @MarcGravell is there a signed version of Dapper?